# Which types of damage for the end game?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

For my first game of Dragon Age Origins I'm playing a mage.  So far I've concentrated exclusively on dealing two types of damage so I can get to the higher level spells faster.  Right now fire is my primary and acid (is this Earth?) is my secondary.  However, I'm worried that I'll encounter opponents resistant to both types which will neuter the effectiveness of my mage.

**What damage types will best carry me through the game?**

(Let me just say that getting my first really good AOE magic attack, *fireball*, has catapulted my mage from dealing about 1/10 of party damage to dealing >1/2 of party damage)

Comment: As a Mage, one ability that you *absolutely should get* is Mana Clash. It only affects targets that have mana, but utterly decimates them (you can one-shot a particular boss with it - it's that powerful).

Comment: Promote that to an answer and you'll get some points :)

Comment: I don't feel it's enough to constitute an answer on its own - however I'll throw something together in a little bit, I have to refamiliarise myself with the magic schools first

Answer (score 2):

The elemental trees are the best for raw damage.

As far as damage goes, the cold tree is a must have. The mind blast tree is good as well. Stonefist is good and Mana Clash is beast.

Comment: One note about Stonefist: despite the game text stating it deals nature damage, it actually deals physical.  Also, nature damage in general should be avoided.  There is only one spell that actually deals that type but many staves also deal that type of damage.  Darkspawn are very resistant to nature damage.  (And, while this isn't end-game related, undead are cold-resistant or cold-immune.)